# Avconv command to combine image and audio file (to create a video)

Tags: python, os.system, avconv, pythonanywhere

Trying to perform a simple task: combine an image file with an audio file to create a video. I've already found a few examples using ffmpeg, but I'm using a cloud-based PythonAnywhere and they only use avconv.

Code would look something like this:

```
import os
image_file = "/dir/greenfrog.jpg"
audio_file = "/dir/AudioFile.wav"
output_file = "/dir/VideoFile.mp4"
cmd = xxxxx
os.system(cmd)
```

How should I write the cmd string to combine the two files? Thanks for your help here...

Answer (score 2):

Here is you command:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:U0x46d0x8ad,0 -ar 
22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4
```